# React js/ javascript code refactor for loop/switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following code where I get 4 different attributes, I need to check each if its true and increment the count

```
var count = 0;
 if (props.isApple) {
   count += 1;
 }
 if (props.isOranges) {
   count += 1;
 }
 if (props.isBanana) {
   count += 1;
 }
 if (props.isJackfruit) {
   count += 1;
 }
 console.log(count);
```

Is there any simple or nicer way of doing this? Any suggestions??

Comment: you can use or condition `||` and append all condition in single if statement

Comment: @Master.Deep in that case even if one attribute is true it will increment the count

Comment: So do you wish to increment count if all the attributes are true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a job for [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const props = {
  isApple: true,
  isOranges: false,
  isBanana: true,
  isJackfruit: true
} // 3 true values

const checks = ["isApple", "isOranges", "isBanana", "isJackfruit"];
const count = checks.reduce((sum, check) => sum + (props[check] ? 1 : 0), 0);
  
console.log("count", count)
```

This iterates the list of *checks* and adds one to the sum if that property is *truthy* in `props`.

If you wanted it to be more dynamic and inclusive of all `prop` properties, you could define `checks` as...

```js
const checks = Object.keys(props)
```

---

Since you've tagged this with [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs), I'd use the [memo hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to avoid unnecessary recalculation

```js
import { useMemo } from "react";

const checks = ["isApple", "isOranges", "isBanana", "isJackfruit"];

const YourComponent = (props) => {
  const count = useMemo(() =>
    checks.reduce((sum, check) => sum + (props[check] ? 1 : 0), 0),
    [ props ]
  );

  // etc
}
```